# bazel rules for the protobuf C++ compiler

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, bazel

I'm using Bazel and Google's protocol buffers. I want to add a Bazel rule so I can generate the C++ API from the `.proto` files. In GNU make, I would do (simplified example):

```
%.h: %.cc
%.cc: %.proto
    protoc --cpp_out=. $<
```

How can I accomplish the same (i.e. generate the API whenever `mymessage.proto` changes) using Bazel?

Comment: Native support for cc_proto_library has recently landed in Bazel: https://bazel.build/blog/2017/02/27/protocol-buffers.html. If that helps you, I'll turn this comment into an answer.

Comment: @user1071136 that would be good!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Native support for `cc_proto_library` has recently landed in Bazel: http://bazel.build/blog/2017/02/27/protocol-buffers.html.

tl;dr, after setting your `WORKSPACE` file once,

```
cc_proto_library(
    name = "person_cc_proto",
    deps = [":person_proto"],
)

proto_library(
    name = "person_proto",
    srcs = ["person.proto"],
    deps = [":address_proto"],
)

...
```

Then,

```
$ bazel build :person_cc_proto
```

---

There's an example at https://github.com/cgrushko/proto_library.

The gist is that you define a `proto_library` to "import" you .proto file into Bazel, and `cc_proto_library` to compile it to C++. The protocol buffer compiler and runtimes are taken by default from `@com_google_protobuf//:protoc` and `@com_google_protobuf_cc//:cc_toolchain`, respectively.

The reason for this separation is to enable large proto graphs that need to be compiled to multiple languages.

Answer (score 8):

I tried the above and it didn't seem to work, I got an error from `protoc` for trying to create two directories, then that the `my-proto.h` directory didn't exist. Instead, I did

```
genrule(
    name = "my-proto-gen",
    outs = ["my-proto.pb.h my-proto.pb.cc"],
    cmd = "$(location //third_party/protobuf:protoc) --cpp_out=$(GENDIR) $<",
    srcs = ["my-proto.proto"],
    tools = ["//third_party/protobuf:protoc"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "my-proto",
    srcs = ["my-proto.pb.cc"],
    hdrs = ["my-proto.pb.h"]
)
```

Which actually just checks to see that the header file is created and creates it `bazel-genfiles` directory.

You can then include the proto build in your `cc_library` as `:my-proto`.

**UPDATE**:
To get this entire thing to work, do the following:

1. Add the following to your WORKSPACE file. This downloads the protobuf library:

   ```
   http_archive(
       name = "protobuf",
       url = "https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.0.0/protobuf-cpp-3.0.0.zip",
       strip_prefix = "protobuf-3.0.0",
   )
   ```
2. Create a .bzl file (let's say protobuf.bzl) and put in the following:

   ```
   def cpp_proto(name, src):
     native.genrule(
         name = "%s-gen" % name,
         outs = ["%s.pb.cc" % name, "%s.pb.h" % name],
         cmd = "$(location @protobuf//:protoc) --cpp_out=$(GENDIR) $<",
         srcs = [src],
         tools = ["@protobuf//:protoc"],
     )

     native.cc_library(
         name = name,
         srcs = ["%s.pb.cc" % name],
         hdrs = ["%s.pb.h" % name],
     )
   ```
3. In your build files, add in `load(':protobuf.bzl', 'cpp_proto')`
4. You can now use the macro as such:

   ```
   cpp_proto(
       name = "my-proto",
       src = "my-proto.proto"
   )

   cc_library(
       name = "my-program",
       srcs = ["my-program.cc"],
       deps = [
           ":my-proto",
       ],
   )
   ```

Comment: This only works if the proto file is in the workspace. If it's in a subfolder, the generated files are not in the folder where bazel expects them to be and fails. I would need to add `--proto_path` to the `protoc` call.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways.  As a one-off, you can just create a genrule to execute the command over certain inputs:

```
genrule(
    name = "my-proto-gen",
    outs = ["my-proto.cc", "my-proto.h"],
    cmd = "$(location //path/to:protoc) --cpp_out=$@ $<",
    srcs = ["my-proto.proto"],
    tools = ["//path/to:protoc"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "my-proto",
    srcs = ["my-proto.cc"],
    hdrs = ["my-proto.h"],
)
```

Based on your make rule, I'd assume you want to do this multiple times. In that case, you can define a *macro* in a .bzl file.  Macros are basically functions that call build rules:

```
# In, say, foo/bar.bzl.
def cpp_proto(name, src):
  native.genrule(
      name = "%s-gen" % name,
      outs = ["%s.cc" % name, "%s.h" % name],
      cmd = "$(location //path/to:protoc) --cpp_out=$@ $<",
      srcs = [src],
      tools = ["//path/to:protoc"],
  )

  native.cc_library(
      name = name,
      srcs = ["%s.cc" % name],
      hdrs = ["%s.h" % name],
  )
```

Then in, say, foo/BUILD, you can import & use your macro to concisely call the rules:

```
load('//foo:bar.bzl', 'cpp_proto')
cpp_proto('my-proto', 'my_proto.proto')
```

Then you can depend on `//foo:my-proto` from `cc_library`s, `cc_binary`s, and `cc_test`s.

Finally, you might want to follow https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/52 (and just use mzhaom's macro).

Comment: Thanks to the pointer to mzhaom's macro, I somehow missed it. However, I didn't really understand how to use it. There were also two other alternatives suggested at the end of the thread, but I couldn't get either of them running. The native protobuf support seems to lack the cpp part, and the pubref rules always threw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

I put together a set of protobuf generating rules at https://github.com/pubref/rules_protobuf.  It supports C++ in additional to a number of other languages.  Hope you find it useful.